# How to remove number from user input in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, validation, nsstring

In my application I have a field for user to enter Full name, but I need to prevent the user from Entering any number and Emoji in the the text field. Any Idea how to do this ?

Meanwhile, I can not use the ASCII keyboard cuz the user must be able to enter in different language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better (IMO) and more concise implementation for the delegate function already mentioned:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    return [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]].location == NSNotFound);
}
```

This creates a character set from every possible character besides the digits 0-9 and then looks for any of them in the string.  This solution correctly handles the empty string which is what gets sent when the user uses the delete key.

If you want to allow punctuation characters other others you can create your own character set with NSMutableCharacterSet or use the NSCharacterSet method

```
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789,.-"];
```

In place of decimalDigitCharacterSet

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying a `field` but not giving more precision about it, so I will suppose we are here talking about `UITextField` since the other control will follow the same logic:

You should first of all design a delegate for your `UITextField`, let's say it will be the current view controller:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface _4644493ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

@end
```

Then, in your viewController.m, you should check wether if the value pressed on the keyboard is an accepted character before accepting the character (let's try with number in this example):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([string isEqual:@"1"] || [string isEqual:@"2"] || [string isEqual:@"3"] || [string isEqual:@"4"] || [string isEqual:@"5"] || [string isEqual:@"6"] || [string isEqual:@"7"] || [string isEqual:@"8"] || [string isEqual:@"9"]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

#### Edit:

Also, do not forget to design the delegate of your `UITextField`, example:

```
UITextField *test = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 200, 30)];
[test.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[test.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
test.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:test];
```

Comment: Thanks, but how about Emoji character, how can I detect them ?

Comment: @SoheilBm that's depend on your emoji implementation, without code I can't guide you, but typically, if you use this logic for allowing only letter, it should be ok

Comment: This answer is far too restrictive. It doesn't handle most of what the OP wants and it doesn't handle a user pasting in text that contains more than one character. Why not simply ensure that `string` only contains characters from the `letterCharacterSet` `NSCharacterSet`? Though you need to allow some punctuation too since many names have some punctuation.

Comment: @rmaddy, thank you for your comment and advice, I will do some research ASAP and try to improve my answer